# Conventional way to code around potential fetch errors?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch

Is it ok to have unhandled Promise rejection on client (React Native)?

Should you really have a .catch on every function that fetches data from a server to handle potential network problems (or a try, catch in case of async await I believe)? Or else your app crashes once it happens?

Interested to hear how this works in practice. I am not sure if I should have these safety measures defined each time a fetching function is called

Comment: I would recommend having the `try catch` for all of them, even if you just want to fail silently. This way you can at least log the errors or do other actions that a user may not see but that you want to care about.

Comment: @maxshuty Thank you. Is that common practice? To have try catch blocks everywhere?

Comment: It just depends on how you have things setup. You could certainly abstract things out a bit and create an `error` function and instead of a try catch on your fetch's you could just do `if (response.success) { // do stuff } else { throw Error('message') }` but then you should have handling setup for that scenario

Comment: Even if your catch doesn't include a `throw new Error` or throws the very same error anywhere else, your future self will probably thank you if you add at least a 
`console.warn(error)` with each `.catch(error=>...)`. This way, you'll avoid spending too much time trying to figure out why you don't get what you expect from a fetch request. Writing catch blocks everywhere is tedious, but the effort is totally worth it.